# Is there a way to fix or reinstall Docker Desktop after deleting files in the Docker directory?

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

I am new to Docker (just about a week) and am trying to get Docker Desktop 3.3.1 to work.  I foolishly deleted some files in the Docker directory, and now cannot uninstall the application.  I have stopped it and unregistered it using **wsl**, but when I go to the **Apps & features** Settings window and click **Uninstall**, it just hangs with a blank **Uninstall** window.
However, when I try to reinstall Docker Desktop 3.3.1, I get the following message:  **"Existing installation is up to date"** but still see the empty **C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker** directory.

I tried to delete the registry key at **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Docker Desktop** but I get **"Cannot delete Docker Desktop: Error while deleting key."*

Is there a "fix" I can download to repair this installation, or is there a way to keep the uninstallation from "hanging"?  Since I can't do anything with Docker Desktop until this is fixed, I am using Docker for Windows.  I am not sure that Docker for Windows has the capabilities and features I need.  I would appreciate any help I can get.
[image: Apps & features window] [image: Uninstall window] [image: Docker Directory]

Comment: did you solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was a key in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` called “Docker for Windows.” I deleted it and all of its sub-keys and the installation then went to completion.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to getting out the "installation existing up to date" is:
First go to the control panel and select all control panel items,
then go to "program and features".
Now search the docker desktop and uninstall it.

Now reinstall docker.

This method worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have Windows 11.

Go to Start and write `regedit`, then go to: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`, and I deleted the complete Docker directory that appears there.

I deleted a Docker directory in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft`.

Then I executed the 'Docker Desktop Installer.exe', and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

open the register editor

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall

Just change version and display version to a number lower than the current version and it will reinstall

[highlighted pic of where to change stuff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQ8tE.png)